# RegEx for dividing complex number String in Java

Tags: java, regex

Looking for a Regular Expression in Java to separate a String that represents complex numbers. A code sample would be great.
The input string will be in the form:

```
"a+bi"
Example: "300+400i", "4+2i", "5000+324i".
```

I need to retrieve 300 & 400 from the String.'

I know we can do it crudely in this way.

```
str.substring(0, str.indexOf('+'));
str.substring(str.indexOf('+')+1,str.indexOf("i"));
```

Comment: Why do you prefer regex over those few very concise lines?

Comment: Just to see if it's possible and the syntax :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to retrieve 300 & 400 from the String.

What about using `String.split(regex)` function:

```
String s[] = "300-400i".split("[\\Q+-\\Ei]");

System.out.println(s[0]+" "+s[1]); //prints 300 400
```

Comment: You forgot to include the possibility of `a-bi`.

Comment: Doesn't include - in the second string.

Comment: Got it, My Bad. Didn't refresh :)

Answer (score 2):

Regex that matches this is: `/[0-9]{1,}[+-][0-9]{1,}i/`

You can use this method:

```
Pattern complexNumberPattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9]{1,}");
Matcher complexNumberMatcher = complexNumberPattern.matcher(myString);
```

and use `find` and `group` methods on `complexNumberMatcher` to retrieve numbers from `myString`

Comment: Hey MJafar, your code worked for me, but I chose Sage's answer for simplicity and lack of imports. But I like the approach :)

Comment: I liked his answer too, very good approach, but remember my code, save it somewhere, it's a way to get substrings that match a specific pattern in a bigger string. This approach also works when input has extra spaces like `300 +400i`. Sage's answer can be corrected with `trim()` method. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this one:

```
[0-9]{1,}
```

It'll return the numbers.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. As for me, it works.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] attempts = new String[]{"300+400i", "4i+2", "5000-324i", "555", "2i", "+400", "-i"};
    for (String s : attempts) {
        System.out.println("Parsing\t" + s);
        printComplex(s);
    }
}

static void printComplex(String in) {
    String[] parts = in.split("[+-]");
    int re = 0, im = 0, pos = -1;
    for (String s : parts) {
        if (pos != -1) {
            s = in.charAt(pos) + s;
        } else {
            pos = 0;
            if ("".equals(s)) {
                continue;
            }
        }
        pos += s.length();
        if (s.lastIndexOf('i') == -1) {
            if (!"+".equals(s) && !"-".equals(s)) {
                re += Integer.parseInt(s);
            }
        } else {
            s = s.replace("i", "");
            if ("+".equals(s)) {
                im++;
            } else if ("-".equals(s)) {
                im--;
            } else {
                im += Integer.parseInt(s);
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Re:\t" + re + "\nIm:\t" + im);
}
```

Output:

```
Parsing 300+400i
Re: 300
Im: 400
Parsing 4i+2
Re: 2
Im: 4
Parsing 5000-324i
Re: 5000
Im: -324
Parsing 555
Re: 555
Im: 0
Parsing 2i
Re: 0
Im: 2
```

Comment: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "+400"

Comment: I posted it more as example. Some if statements solve problem. See update

Answer (score 0):

Regex

```
([-+]?\d+\.?\d*|[-+]?\d*\.?\d+)\s*\+\s*([-+]?\d+\.?\d*|[-+]?\d*\.?\d+)i
```

Example Regex

```
http://rubular.com/r/FfOAt1zk0v
```

**Example Java**

```
string regexPattern =
            // Match any float, negative or positive, group it
            @"([-+]?\d+\.?\d*|[-+]?\d*\.?\d+)" +
            // ... possibly following that with whitespace
            @"\s*" +
            // ... followed by a plus
            @"\+" +
            // and possibly more whitespace:
            @"\s*" +
            // Match any other float, and save it
            @"([-+]?\d+\.?\d*|[-+]?\d*\.?\d+)" +
            // ... followed by 'i'
            @"i";
        Regex regex = new Regex(regexPattern);

        Console.WriteLine("Regex used: " + regex);

        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Write a number: ");
            string imgNumber = Console.ReadLine();
            Match match = regex.Match(imgNumber);

            double real = double.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            double img = double.Parse(match.Groups[2].Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            Console.WriteLine("RealPart={0};Imaginary part={1}", real, img);
        }
```

Comment: Can it be modified to handle - for the imaginary part?
It currently only handles negative values for the real part.

Also if the imaginary part is given in the first part?

Answer (score 0):

In theory you could use something like this:

```
Pattern complexNumberPattern = Pattern.compile("(.*)+(.*)");
Matcher complexNumberMatcher = complexNumberPattern.matcher(myString);
if (complexNumberMatcher.matches()) {
  String prePlus = complexNumberMatcher.group(1);
  String postPlus = complexNumberMatcher.group(2);
}
```

The advantage this would give you over selecting the numbers, is that it would allow you to read things like:
5b+17c as 5b and 17c

edit: just noticed you didn't want the letters, so never mind, but this would give you more control over it in case other letters appear in it.